# How to create an event for Milestone for User facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to create an event for Milestone an everyday event such as weight loss using Facebook Graph API

like:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
"/{page-id}/milestones",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

but instead of the page, making the user using, like:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
"/me/milestones",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

Comment: Users can not have milestones, only pages can.

Comment: i can create "life event" from graph API? how nike create a vent for running and bike? from de apps